# amortized bound of sorted linked list

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, sorting, amortized-analysis

I am trying to prove that the amortized complexity of  insert operation in a **sorted** LinkedList is O(1).
I know that the worst case time is O(n) but finding it hard to find an appropriate potential function.
I'll be glad if someone could help.

Thanks.

Comment: The statement you're trying to prove is so obviously false that I suspect you mean something different when you write "amortized". What's the context, and what do you understand amortized complexity to mean?

Comment: @delnan amortized as i mean is kind of avarage. and the idea that the amortized cost is O(1) is from wikipedia..

Comment: Average across a number of operations (as opposed to the time for a single operation with average parameters), yes. Where specifically does Wikipedia say that?

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_data_structure

Comment: Oh my, that's misleading. Adding the node is O(1) when you have a reference to the node before/after, but you first need to find that position. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3899456/395760

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O(1) amortized means that a sequence of n insertions costs O(n) time in the worst case. This is not true for this case because inserting the elements in reverse order takes O(n*n).